# Drag and Drop color change with Android ListView

Tags: android

I am currently creating an Android app which needs to let the user know which players have been selected from the listview. Each player can only be played three times so I was hoping to change the color of the background on the listview each time a name is selected.

At the moment when I click an item it will turn green. When a different item is clicked in the listview it will turn yellow. However, I want the count to be on the same listview item.

I have pasted my code below. Would anyone be able to tell me how count the number of clicks on a single listview item at one time?

```
TextView text1 = (TextView)v;
if (numberOfClicks == 1) 
{
    text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
} 
else if (numberOfClicks == 2) 
{
    text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW); 
    v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
} 
else if (numberOfClicks == 3) 
{
    text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
}
numberOfClicks++;
```

Answer (score 0):

declare an array of int in adapter:

```
int[] numberOfClicks;
```

in the constructor of the adapter initialize it.

```
numberOfClicks=new int[data.size()];
```

now in `getView`

```
    TextView text1 = (TextView)v;
    if(numberOfClicks[position]==1)
    {
        text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    }

    else if (numberOfClicks[position]==2)
      {
         text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);    
         v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
      }

    else if (numberOfClicks[position]==3)
      {
          text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
          v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
      }
        numberOfClicks[position]++;
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your response. I tried to implement your code however I'm having some issues. I haven't declared an adapter to place the numberOfClicks=new int[data.size()]; 
Would you have any advice on how to implement this? This is the beginning of my method:
OnItemLongClickListener longListen = new OnItemLongClickListener()
{
 @Override
 public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                int pos, long id){

Comment: so declare this in your activity. and put this code in onItemLongClick

Comment: Thanks again. I tried to do it that way however, I'm still having problems with numberOfClicks=new int[data.size()]; 
I declared int[] numberOfClicks; at the start of my activity. I then put numberOfClicks=new int[data.size()]; in the onItemLongClick before I started the if statement. I also tried declaring data as a variable but this didn't seem to work for me either! Do you know where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: don't put numberOfClicks=new int[data.size()];  in the onItemLongClick. Put it in the onCreate or just after the data is set

Answer (score 0):

it is spike, but can work:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> mClickedMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        ...
if (mClickedMap.get(v)==1){
    text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
} 
        ...
mClickedMap.put(v,numberOfClicks++);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I tried to implement this however I seem to be getting a null pointer exception. Would you know how to fix this please?